# Scraping all videos from a tiktok profile

Tags: html, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a tool that downloads every video from a given user on TikTok at once.  example page: https://www.tiktok.com/@levelsofpiano . I started by examining the html tree on a TikTok profile which revealed these "a" tags that hold links to the video pages for each video that's loaded on the page.

[image: 'a' tag]

I tried to use `wget` to capture the page using `wget https://www.tiktok.com/@levelsofpiano > Output.html`, however there is no mention even of `@levelsofpiano` in the resulting html. I'm guessing the content on the site is loaded dynamically, so poor `wget` gets a mostly empty page.

I then decided to use `testcafe` (UI testing tool like Selenium) to load the page, wait 20 seconds, and capture the html output... but the videos don't load when I use this method:
[image]

Here's my script:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
import fs from 'fs';

let username = "levelsofpiano";
fixture `Get Dat Tiktok`.page("https://www.tiktok.com/@" + username);

function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); }

/* got this definition from https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/can-i-save-a-web-page-as-an-html-file/461 */
const getPageHTML = ClientFunction(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML);

test('Capture page with loaded elements', async t => {
    await sleep(20000); //20 seconds
    await fs.writeFile('./' + username + '.html',await getPageHTML(), function(err, result) {
        if(err) console.log('error', err);
    });    
});
```

What else can I try to scrape all these videos?  I'm likely going to need a way to scroll through the page to load all videos as well (which I could do with testcafe or selenium.. if I could find a way to get them to load the content I'm looking for)

Answer (score 1):

It's surprising there's no API to get all user videos. I came up with this hacky solution which will first parse the DOM for the already loaded videos on the page, then sets up an XHR override to parse the JSON in the network requests triggered by an auto-scroller. After you paste this in the console, you'll need to wait for it to run (don't scroll manually) and then you can log `allVideos` to see the array of video IDs.

Alternative, you can just use the auto-scroller function and keep parsing the DOM with the continuously loaded videos.

```js
window.allVideos = [];
getInitialVideoIDs();

const origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url) {
  this.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && isVideoFetch(url)) {
      const responseData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      pushVideoIDs(responseData);
      checkAutoScroller(responseData);
    }
  });
  origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};

const autoScroller = setInterval(function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}, 1000);

function isVideoFetch(url) {
  const videoFetchRegEx = /\/api\/post\/item_list\//;
  return videoFetchRegEx.test(url);
}

function pushVideoIDs(responseData) {
  responseData.itemList.forEach(item => {
    if (allVideos.indexOf(item.id) === -1) {
      allVideos.push(item.id);
    }
  });
} 

function checkAutoScroller(responseData) {
  if (!responseData.hasMore) {
    clearInterval(autoScroller);
  }
}

function getInitialVideoIDs() {
  const videos = document.querySelectorAll('.tt-feed .video-feed-item-wrapper');
  videos.forEach(video => {
    const urlObj = new URL(video.href);
    const path = urlObj.pathname;
    const id = (path.match(/\/video\/(\d+)/) || [])[1];
    allVideos.push(id);
  });
}
```

Comment: is this still work ?
because i tried but no luck 
i used brave console at this page https://www.tiktok.com/@khaled_alatwi55/

Answer (score 0):

The previous codes don't work for me either, but this one works fine (using the Chrome console on a TikTok channel page).

```
//COPY & PASTE CODE 1:

let goToBottom = setInterval(() => window.scrollBy(0, 400), 1000);
```

(Wait until scroll finishes)

```
//COPY & PASTE CODE 2:

clearInterval(goToBottom);
let arrayVideos = [];
console.log('\n'.repeat(50));
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="-DivItemContainerV2"]');  
for (const container of containers) {
    const link = container.querySelector('[data-e2e="user-post-item"] a');
    const title = container.querySelector('[data-e2e="user-post-item-desc"] a');
    //If the link is https://www.tiktok.com/, set it as the current page URL
    if (link.href === 'https://www.tiktok.com/') link.href = window.location.href;
    arrayVideos.push(title.title + ';' + link.href);
    console.log(title.title + '\t' + link.href);
}
```

Optional, download as CSV:

//COPY & PASTE CODE 3:

```
let data = arrayVideos.join('\n');
let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/csv'});
let elem = window.document.createElement('a');
elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
elem.download = 'my_data.csv';
document.body.appendChild(elem);
elem.click();
document.body.removeChild(elem);
```

Source: https://responsive-muse.com/export-tiktok-channel-video-titles-urls-using-javascript/